# Does iPhone using ARMv7 instructions supports ARMv6 compiled binaries?

Tags: ios, iphone, armv7, armv6

Is it possible to run armv6 compiled binaries on a device that has the armv7 support (iPhone 3GS+) ?

For example, can I use a library that has been compiled with the armv6 instructions on an iPhone 5?

Comment: XCode 4.5 has no support for armv6 anymore. So if you have a library that only contains armv6 code, you can no longer use it with the latest XCode though all the devices (iPhone 3G up to iPhone 5) would support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. ARMv7 is backwards compatible with ARMv6.